# Why is super used so much in PySide/PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, super

**Short version (tl;dr)**

I am learning PySide, and most online tutorials use `super` to initialize UI elements. Is this important (i.e., more scalable), or is it a matter of taste?

*Clarification*: as I make more clear in the detailed version, this is not another generic thread asking when to use `super` (this has been done before). Rather, given the number of PySide tutorials that use `super` instead of `<class>.__init__`, I am trying to figure out if using `super` is standard in PySide applications? If so, is it because the circumstances where `super` is called for (involving resolving inheritances) come up a lot specifically in the use of PySide/PyQt? Or is it a matter of taste.

**Detailed version**

I am new to Python, and presently learning PySide using Zets tutorial (http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/firstprograms/). The second example in the tutorial includes:

```
from PySide import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):      
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300,300,250,150)
        self.setWindowTitle("PySide 101: Window the First!")
        self.show()

app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex=Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This works fine, but I have never used `super`. Hence, I rewrote the above code, successfully replacing `super` with more standard explicit invocation of the parent class:

```
QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
```

But as I search the web for PySide tutorials (e.g., http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide-Newbie-Tutorials), they *all* include calls to `super`. My question is: should I use `super` for PySide scripting?

It seems that `super` seems most helpful when you have inheritance diamonds, that it tends to resolve instances of multiple inheritance in a reasonable way. Is `super` used a lot with PySide because there is a preponderance of cases of such diamonds that I will confront with more realistic complicated examples? *[Edit: No: see my answer below.]*

*Why am I even asking?* Why not just use `super` and be done with it?

I am asking because the book I am using to learn Python (Learning Python, by Lutz) spends over 20 pages on the topic of `super`, and *explicitly cautions against using it*. He suggests that new Python users go with the more traditional, explicit route before messing with it (e.g., see page 832, and pages 1041-1064 of Learning Python, 5th Edition). He basically paints it as a nonPythonic, arcane, rarely actually needed, new style that you should treat with great caution when just starting out, and thinks it is overused by experienced users.

Further, looking at the source code of two major PySide/PyQt based projects (Spyder and pyqtgraph), neither uses `super`. One (Spyder) explicitly tells contributors to avoid using it for compatibility reasons (http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/wiki/NoteForContributors).

Note I link to a closely related post below, but the answer there discusses more generally when you would want to use `super` (when you have multiple inheritance). My question is whether PySide scripting justifies, or even requires, the use of `super` in the long term, or whether it is more Pythonic, and better for compatibility reasons, to explicitly name parent classes? Or is it a matter of taste?

If it is frowned upon (as my beginner book suggests) why is it so ubiquitous in PySide tutorials aimed at beginners? If it makes any difference, it seems the people writing these tutorials are seasoned Java programmers, or catering to such programmers. I am not.

**Related topics**

http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2008-January/018320.html

[Different ways of using __init__ for PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597436/different-ways-of-using-init-for-)

[Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods?rq=1)

Comment: Personally, I use `<class>.__init(self,...)`, but I did recently get bitten by this when I originally subclassed (let's say) `QWidget` and overrode a bunch of methods, calling the parent class method at some point within. Later I changed my class to subclass `QMainWindow` and forgot to change all of the `QWidget.<method>` calls over. Using `super()` would have made it easier.

Comment: @three_pineapples so it wasn't a case of inheritance resolution, but largely one of code refactoring? Interesting.

Comment: No, It was for inheritance resolution (well I'd call it inheritance resolution). In a complex subclass you don't just want to call `parent_cls.__init__` but other methods when you extend the functionality (for instance your implementation of `getText()` might want to call `parent_cls.getText()`). Using `super` avoids having to manually update the parent_cls in each place you've used it.

Comment: Right: I meant multiple inheritance (with diamonds and such).

Comment: Hello from 2017! [Nowadays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608134/why-is-python-3-xs-super-magic) the syntax just `super().__init__()` which is even shorter than `BaseClass.__init__(self)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is nothing  wrong with instantiating parent classes in the traditional way, and some things to be said in favor of it. That said, using `super` simplifies the creation of subclasses, and the future modifications of one's PySide code, and people seem to have latched onto the latter as the overriding factor. This is not specific to Pyside, but to object-oriented programming in Python more generally (as pointed out in Kos's excellent answer).

The potential for simplification of code modification comes because within PySide it is necessary for things to work to define subclasses based on other `QtGui` objects (e.g., `QtQui.QMainWindow` and `QtGui.QWidget`). Further, people tend to futz around with their parent classes enough so that it seems easier to just use `super`, so that you you don't have to update your __init__ method every time you change parents.

So it isn't a matter of using `super` to help resolve cases of multiple inheritance, the case where most people agree it is probably best suited. Rather, it is a matter of doing less work within __init__ in case your parent class changes in the future.

Here are the responses from each author, both of whom wrote what I consider to be good PySide tutorials:

**Author 1:**

> I think it is a matter of taste. Earlier tutorials (PyQt and PySide)
>   used .**init** and later I switched to super(). I personally
>   prefer super().

**Author 2:**

> The reason people use super instead of .**init**(...) is to
>   avoid making changes if you change what the parent class is, e.g. if
>   you switch from QVBoxLayout to QHBoxLayout, you only have to change it
>   in the class definition line, rather than in the **init** method as
>   well.

So there you have it. Not these benefits aren't really specific to PySide, but to writing subclasses/inheritance more generally.

I'm not sure what Lutz, who seems very hesitant to endorse the use of `super`, would say (perhaps using `super` violates the 'Explicit is better than implicit' maxim).

**Update Four Years Later**
In retrospect, this debate is sort of over and this question is almost quaint (this was my first question at SO). While there used to be debate about the use of `super`, these debates are sort of over. Especially in Python 3 `super`'s convenience has proven itself and just makes your code easier to maintain. Because in Qt/Pyside/PyQt framework the use of inheritance from more abstract Qt classes is ubiquitous, this is no small feature. Sure, you will need to be careful when you have crazy lattices of inheritance, but frankly since I asked this question, I have literally never run into this problem, and I currently use `super` in all my code. It *arguably* violates the "explicit is better than implicit" maxim, but "Simple is better than complex" and "practicality beats purity" are the overriding factors here (the practical aspect here is "maintainability counts").

Comment: Thanks for the direct follow with the authors.  This is very helpful commentary.

Answer (score 11):

Hm, nice one. But IMO it's only barely related to Qt/ PySide.

First, how are these two different? If you have simple inheritance (perhaps not counting "mixins"), then there's no difference in behaviour. A cosmetic difference remains- you don't need to name your base class again - but you do have to name the same class.

The differences start when you have multiple inheritance. Then a chain of `super()` calls for this hierarchy:

```
          A
        /   \
       X     Y
        \   /
          Z
```

can easily proceed like this through `super()` calls:

```
          A
            \
       X --- Y
        \   
          Z
```

without the need of X and Y knowing each other. This relates to the concept of [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) that allows a style of programming called "cooperative multiple inheritance" in [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).

If there's a method `Foo` and implementations in X and Y of that method build upon A's implementation, then Z is easily able to rely on both X and Y without them knowing even about each other. This, however, has an important precondition: `Foo` has the same (or at least [compatible]) signature in every class, as specified by `A`'s interface where it's initially defined.

The `__init__` method is special: technically it works in exactly the same way with `super`, but! but (more often than not) for subclasses it has a totally different signature. If the subclass' `__init__` looks different, then `super` won't give you anything over explicit base call because you aren't able to use cooperative multitasking anyway.

Note: Python is very atypical in this respect: in most OO languages constructors belong to the class, rather than the instances; in other words most languages rely on their equivalents of `__new__` and don't have `__init__` at all.

Note 2: I have never seen any real code that would rely of cooperative multiple inheritance. (Single inheritance easily makes enough spaghetti for me ;-))

Also, some good reading:

- [Method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) - what's it all about
- [Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it](http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/)

[

Comment: Upvote for a nice explanation of multiple inheritance type situations. However, the crux of my question is the relation to PySide. Are such situations something that happens so often in PySide programming to make it something that should be done, and does this explain why super is ubiquitous in the beginner PySide tutorials? That is, in the context of PySide scripting, does this come up so often that it would be silly to not use super? Or is it a byproduct of the fact that most of the tutorials are strangely Java-centric (where super is more natural)?

Comment: I'd guess the fact that is used ubiquitously is due to the fact that once you've decided to use `super`, rather than `<class>.__init__`, it's simply better style to be consistent, rather than to switch between all possible variations. Which is clearly demonstrated by the "confusion" described in your first related topic.

Comment: Seems like it is basically a matter of taste, so because I'm scared of super (From Lutz's book), I'll just do the older way. I did find a recent tutorial that does it that way: http://www.pythoncentral.io/series/python-pyside-pyqt-tutorial/

Comment: +1 for your comment on the signature of the `__init__` function.  If the signature changes, then you have to call with `<class>.__init__` to make sure you pass acceptable arguments.  On a side note, I started feeling much more comfortable with OOP when I stopped using super.  Zen of Python: "Explicit is better than implicit".  I am also a child of Lutz.  =)